# A practice shared_ptr implementation

Tags: c++, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel

I am trying to build a class similar to `std::shared_ptr` just to learn and improve my way of thinking. I am hoping that you can tell me if this implementation is correct? If so, how can I improve it?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<typename dataType>
class shared_ptr
{
public:
    shared_ptr()
    {
        id++;
        internalId = id;
        countMap[id] = 1;
        ptr = new dataType();
    }
    shared_ptr(shared_ptr& a)
    {
        this->ptr = a.ptr;
        this->internalId = a.internalId;
        countMap[internalId]++;
    }

    void operator=(shared_ptr& a)
    {
        this->ptr = a.ptr;
        this->internalId = a.internalId;
        countMap[internalId]++;
    }

    ~shared_ptr()
    {
        countMap[internalId]--;
        if(countMap[internalId]==0)
        {
            delete ptr;
            countMap.erase(internalId);
        }
    }

private:
    static int id;
    int internalId = 0;
    static std::map<int,int> countMap;
    dataType* ptr;
};
template<typename  dataType>
 int shared_ptr<dataType>::id = 1;
 template<typename  dataType>
 std::map<int,int> shared_ptr<dataType>::countMap;

int main()
{
    {
    shared_ptr<int> sp1;
    {
        shared_ptr<int> sp3;
        shared_ptr<int> sp4(sp3);
        shared_ptr<int> sp5;
        sp5 = sp4;
    }
    shared_ptr<int> sp2(sp1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know `std::map` isn't thread-safe, right?  So you're intentionally only making a single-threaded version of shared_ptr, not trying to get all the lock-free atomics right?  That's fine, but you'd normally want to say so.

Comment: Yeah you are right

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Design review

Trying to roll your own `shared_ptr` is actually a really good practice project. This is not true for many other standard library components, but it is true for `shared_ptr`. You could try to duplicate the behaviour of `std::shared_ptr` *exactly*… but you don’t *need* to, because there are actually many, many different smart pointer designs. The ones in the standard library are just nice general-purpose smart pointers, but it’s *very* common to see custom smart pointers in libraries built for specific purposes.

Your `shared_ptr` actually has one important benefit over `std::shared_ptr`: it’s usually going to be half the size. The reason for that is `std::shared_ptr` uses a control block to keep track of how many shared pointers share the same pointer (among other things), so in a `std::shared_ptr`, there’s usually the actual pointer, and then the pointer to the control block… that’s two pointers, so double the size of a single pointer. You use a static map instead, so each of your shared pointers only holds the actual pointer. That could be an important benefit.

*However*, you also truck around an `int` as an ID. Is that necessary? Why not just use the pointer value itself as the key?

Something like so:

```
std::unordered_map<std::uintptr_t, std::size_t> count_map;

template <typename T>
class shared_ptr
{
public:
    constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept = default;

    explicit shared_ptr(T* p) : _ptr{p}
    {
        _increment_count();
    }

    shared_ptr(shared_ptr const& other) : _ptr{other._ptr}
    {
        _increment_count();
    }

    ~shared_ptr()
    {
        if (_ptr)
        {
            // find the iterator to the count
            //
            // this is better than `count_map[n]` because we might need to use
            // the iterator more than once: once to decrement and check the
            // count, and possibly once more to erase
            auto const n = static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(_ptr);
            if (auto const p = count_map.find(n); p != count_map.end())
            {
                // decrease the count, and see if it's zero
                if (--(p->second) == 0)
                {
                    delete _ptr;

                    // remove the map entry tracking the pointer
                    count_map.erase(p);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // something went really wrong!
                //
                // you should never get here unless there's a bug somewhere
            }
        }
    }

    auto operator=(shared_ptr const& other) -> shared_ptr&
    {
        auto temp = other;

        std::ranges::swap(_ptr, temp->_ptr);

        return *this;
    }

    // other stuff...

private:
    auto _increment_count() -> void
    {
        if (_ptr)
        {
            // convert the pointer to a number
            auto const n = static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(_ptr);

            // add the number as a new key in the count map
            //
            // note that if the key already exists, this will just increment the
            // count, so your shared_ptr will safely work with duplicates...
            // something std::shared_ptr won't do!
            ++(count_map[n]);
        }
    }

    T* _ptr = nullptr;
};
```

By using the pointer value itself as the key, rather than an `int` ID, your `shared_ptr` can now be the size of a single raw pointer.

So your design—using an external map to keep track of the count—has some benefits: notably it is now possible to make your smart pointer the same size as a raw pointer. But, of course, it has some drawbacks:

1. If you have a lot of `shared_ptr`s, that map can get *huge*.
2. Copying and destroying your `shared_ptr`s will be *slow*. `std::shared_ptr` has the pointer to the control block right on hand, so it just needs to do a single pointer indirection. Especially for making copies (and increasing the count), that’s *fast* (relatively speaking). Your `shared_ptr` has to search through a map (which is probably not going to be hot in cache) for each operation. That means that while `auto sp1 = sp2;` is really fast for `std::shared_ptr` it will be slow for your `shared_ptr` (and will get slower the more pointers you have). But that’s a pretty standard engineering size-versus-speed trade-off; your `shared_ptr` takes up less space, at the cost of speed.

### Testing

Rather than simply wondering whether your code works or not, you should test it.

Now, something like `shared_ptr` is not *easy* to test… but not impossible. As a start, you could run your `shared_ptr` through all of its operations, and use a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for bad memory access or leaks. Actually properly unit-testing something like `shared_ptr` is complex, and way beyond the scope here.

But a really easy trick is to simply insert a bunch of `std::cout` statements in your class member functions to print all the data about what’s going on. Yes, this isn’t the “sexy” way to test your code, but you’re a beginner; focus more on your code actually being correct than on doing things the “sexy” way.

In your destructor, you should also print the contents of the count map. That will give you a way to spot leaks, or other problems with the counts.

As I said, this isn’t technically the “right” way to do testing, but screw it, it’s quick, it’s easy, and it works. Even I develop code this way sometimes, if I’m experimenting with something difficult or “clever”. It’s cheap and hacky, but in the early stages of figuring something out, it does the job.

## Code review

For starters, you should really be putting your own classes and stuff into your own, personal namespace. For example, I always use `indi`:

```
namespace indi {

template <typename T>
class shared_ptr
{
    // ... [snip] ...
};

} // namespace indi

auto main() -> int
{
    indi::shared_ptr<int> sp1;
    // ...
}
```

Putting your stuff in your own namespace is a good habit to get into in any case.

```
template<typename dataType>
```

`dataType` is a bad name for a template parameter. By convention, template parameters are written in “`UpperCamelCase`”. Also by convention, `T` is most commonly used. And it’s a hell of a lot shorter than `dataType`.

```
    shared_ptr()
    {
        id++;
        internalId = id;
        countMap[id] = 1;
        ptr = new dataType();
    }
```

Your default constructor actually allocates a new object. That’s… not a great idea. Default construction should be simple, fast, and—ideally—no fail.

Not only that, this behaviour is pretty surprising for a pointer. Consider:

```
using pointer = int*;

auto p1 = pointer{};                // p1 == nullptr, no-fail and fast
auto p2 = std::unique_ptr<int>{};   // p2 == nullptr, no-fail and fast
auto p3 = std::shared_ptr<int>{};   // p3 == nullptr, no-fail and fast
auto p4 = shared_ptr<int>{};        // p4 != nullptr, very slow, and the allocation might throw
```

Default construction for every other smart pointer I’ve seen gives you a null pointer. That should be the case for your smart pointer, too.

If you want a constructor that actually allocates the object—which is a good idea—you can use a “tagged constructor”. A good tag is `std::in_place`:

```
    constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept = default;

    explicit shared_ptr(std::in_place_t)
    {
        id++;
        internalId = id;
        countMap[id] = 1;
        ptr = new dataType();
    }
```

And you’d use it like this:

```
auto sp1 = shared_ptr<int>{std::in_place};
```

You could get even more advanced with perfect forwarding:

```
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit shared_ptr(std::in_place_t, Args&&... args)
    {
        id++;
        internalId = id;
        countMap[id] = 1;
        ptr = new dataType{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }
```

So now you could do:

```
auto sp = shared_ptr<std::string>{std::in_place, '*', 8};
// sp points to a string containing 8 asterisks
```

But let’s dig into the meat of the constructor:

```
    shared_ptr()
    {
        id++;
        internalId = id;
        countMap[id] = 1;
        ptr = new dataType();
    }
```

1. The first line can’t fail. So no problems yet (or so it seems!).
2. The second line also can’t fail. This is the only safe line in this entire constructor. (And even then, it’s not *perfectly* safe; it would be dangerous in concurrent code. But concurrency is a whole other beast.)
3. This line can fail. When you do `countMap[id]`, the map will try to find a key matching `id`, and will (presumably) fail. So it will need to allocate a new node. That allocation might fail. This won’t be *too* serious a problem… all it means is that you’ll skip an ID.
4. This line can also fail, either in the allocation phase, or the construction of the new object. Either way, this is bad, because now `countMap` holds a node with an ID and count of 1 that will never be freed. Since no other shared pointer will use the same ID, this is only a *minor* leak… but it’s still a leak.

If you don’t care about losing IDs, you could fix this constructor by doing something like so:

```
    shared_ptr()
    {
        id++;
        internalId = id;
        countMap[id] = 1;

        try
        {
            ptr = new dataType();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            countMap.erase(id);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But the moral here is to always consider which expressions can throw, and what that means for the function as a whole.

```
    shared_ptr(shared_ptr& a)
    {
        this->ptr = a.ptr;
        this->internalId = a.internalId;
        countMap[internalId]++;
    }
```

The correct form for a copy constructor is to take the argument by `const` reference.

Failure to do so means this code won’t work:

```
auto const sp1 = shared_ptr<int>{};
auto const sp2 = sp1; // won't compile
```

Other than that, this copy constructor is okay. Most C++ programmers would gripe about the `this->` stuff, because it’s unnecessary and ugly, but it’s not actually *wrong*, or harmful. (You could also use a member initializer list, but meh. For these simple types it doesn’t *really* matter.)

```
    void operator=(shared_ptr& a)
    {
        this->ptr = a.ptr;
        this->internalId = a.internalId;
        countMap[internalId]++;
    }
```

@1201ProgramAlarm has already pointed out one of the bugs in this function, but the best way to fix it is to rethink the whole function entirely, and use the “copy-and-swap” technique.

You see, if you follow @1201ProgramAlarm’s advice directly… you’ll have another problem. Let me show you—suppose you did this:

```
auto operator=(shared_ptr const& a) -> shared_ptr&
{
    // first decrement the count of the current pointer, and delete if necessary
    --countMap[internalId];
    if (countMap[internalId] == 0)
        delete ptr;

    // now set the new data
    ptr = a.ptr;
    internalId = a.internalId;
    ++countMap[internalId];

    return *this;
}
```

This looks innocuous… but it’s a trap. It won’t explode easily, but it will explode if you do this:

```
auto sp = shared_ptr<int>{};
sp = sp; // self-assignment
```

Consider what happens during the self-assignment above. Before the self-assignment, the count for the pointer is 1 (because it’s the only smart pointer that owns it). So the first line of the assignment operator does the decrement… and now the count is zero. So, of course, the object gets freed.

Then the “new” data gets transferred over. But… the new data is the same as the old data. So `ptr` is set to… itself… the pointer which now points to the deleted object. `internalId` is also set to itself, but that’s harmless. Then the count gets *re*-incremented, so it goes from zero to one again.

The net result is that your shared pointer *appears* to still be working—still keeping the count to some pointer—but the pointer points to deleted memory. If you access it, boom. And of course, when the last shared pointer pointing to it is destroyed, it will try to free it again. Double `delete`. Boom.

So I recommend the “copy-and-swap” technique:

```
auto operator=(shared_ptr const& a) -> shared_ptr&
{
    // copy a into a temporary...
    auto temp = a;

    // ... then swap the contents of the temporary with this
    std::ranges::swap(ptr, temp->ptr);                  // cannot fail
    std::ranges::swap(internalId, temp->internalId);    // cannot fail

    return *this;

    // when temp goes out of scope, it will be destroyed
    //
    // since it now holds the *OLD* internalID that this had, it will
    // decrement *THAT* count, and if it's zero, free the *OLD* ptr this held
    //
    // in the case of self-assignment, all the copy will do is increase the
    // count (to 2), and then the destruction will decrease it (back to 1),
    // so no harm, no foul
}
```

“Copy-and-swap” is technically less efficient… but it avoids very subtle bugs, like the self-assignment bug I described. You should do “copy-and-swap” in copy assignment operators by default.

Also, your copy-assignment operator is malformed. It should take a `const` reference, and it should return a non-`const` reference to `this`… not `void`.

The destructor is fine, so I’ll skip it.

```
    static int id;
    int internalId = 0;
    static std::map<int,int> countMap;
```

Okay, there are a couple of issues here.

First, I don’t know if you realize it, but since `shared_ptr` is a template, that means that there will be *multiple* `id` and `countMap` objects… one for each template parameter set.

In other words:

```
auto sp1 = shared_ptr<int>{};
auto sp2 = shared_ptr<long>{};
```

You probably think that the `internalId` for `sp1` will be 2, and for `sp2` it will be 3. Nope. It will be 2 for *both*. Why? Because `sp1` is using `shared_ptr<int>::id`, and `sp2` is using `shared_ptr<long>::id`. Those are two different `int`s.

In fact:

```
auto sp01 = shared_ptr<char>{};
auto sp02 = shared_ptr<signed char>{};
auto sp03 = shared_ptr<unsigned char>{};
auto sp04 = shared_ptr<int>{};
auto sp05 = shared_ptr<unsigned int>{};
auto sp06 = shared_ptr<short>{};
auto sp07 = shared_ptr<unsigned short>{};
auto sp08 = shared_ptr<long>{};
auto sp09 = shared_ptr<unsigned long>{};
auto sp10 = shared_ptr<std::string>{};
auto sp11 = shared_ptr<std::u8string>{};
auto sp12 = shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>{};
auto sp13 = shared_ptr<std::vector<long>>{};
```

The above code will create *thirteen* different `id` `int`s, and *thirteen* different `countMap` `std::map<int, int>`s. Every unique type you instantiate a `shared_ptr` with will create a new `id` and `countMap`. If you make `shared_ptr`s using many different types, that will balloon your static memory usage. And the bad thing about static memory usage is that it exists for the *whole* program. It is created when the program starts *even if you never actually use it*, and it exists until the program ends, even if you’re long done with it. Indeed, if you only allocate a *single* `shared_ptr<foo>` one time in the middle of your program, you’re paying for it for the whole program. You’re even paying for it if you allocate *zero* `shared_ptr<foo>` objects… but only *mention* one as a conditional possibility!

So this is not good. You probably only want a single map and `id` counter for *all* types in your program. To do that, you need to pull those static objects out of the template. You have multiple options for how you can do that. You can simply use global objects (probably hidden in a detail namespace). Or you can use a non-template base class and put all the statics in there.

Another issue is the use of `int` for both the ID and the count. `int` is only guaranteed to hold 65,536 values, though in practice it will usually hold at least 4,294,967,296. Four billion sounds like a lot, and it probably is, but it is not inconceivable that if a program runs long enough, and does enough allocating and deallocating, it could run out. (Far more likely to have that happen if you only have 65,536 values, of course.)

Whenever you’re keeping a count of something, the standard type to use in C++ is `std::size_t`. On most 64-bit systems, this will give you at 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 different IDs. That should be enough. You should use this for *both* the ID and the count.

So, perhaps you might do this:

```
// these could be hidden in a detail namespace, or a base class
//
// watch out for the static initialization order fiasco!
static auto next_id = std::size_t{0}; // in C++23 "= 0uz;" would work
static auto count_map = std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t>{};

// since the static variables are not in the template, they won't be
// duplicated for every T
template <typename T>
class shared_ptr
{
    // ...
};
```

Finally, you should consider using `std::unordered_map` rather than `std::map`. You don’t need the ordering, and the unordered map may be faster.

All that’s left is `main()`:

```
shared_ptr<int> sp1;
```

You should really avoid this kind of declaration. The gold standard in modern C++ is the “always `auto`” style:

```
auto sp1 = shared_ptr<int>{};
```

There are a number of reasons why this form is better, too many to get into here. But as a bonus, once you get in the habit of using `auto`, numerous other bugs and quirks go away, and many lines of code become simpler. For example, instead of:

```
shared_ptr<int> sp2(sp1);
```

You could just do:

```
auto sp2 = sp1;
```

Shorter, simpler, clearer, and it avoids all kinds of bugs.

Comment: Thank your for your review , I enjoyed it the most and it is very detailed. again thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Note that using the pointer value as the key prevents pointers from sharing ownership if they don't point to the same address, which has dire consequences for pointing to base/derived classes. It may not be relevant for this simple educational `shared_ptr`, but would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Regarding the cost of maintaining a std::map, I found that it is both slow and has a lot of space overhead. The std::unordered_map is often better, though the default hash function for pointers is usually very bad. Last time I needed a "pointer to size_t" map, I [rolled my own](https://www.github.com/fg-netzwerksicherheit/ShadowHeap/tree/master/src/store/CachedMetaStore.h) which let me avoid the usual standard library inefficiencies (still not thread-safe, though). A control block might need more space, but makes lock-free refcounting much easier.

Comment: Another shared_ptr design which I learned from the Rust standard library is to have your smart pointer share an object that includes both a count and the object, e.g. `struct SharedValue { std::atomic<size_t> count; T value }`. Very compact and cache-efficient. But Angew's remark about casts applies as well.

Comment: What's the difference between `std::swap` and `std::ranges::swap` that makes you want to use it here, when you are not otherwise using ranges?

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO I mean, if you violate the interface contract of *any* type—even `std::shared_ptr`—you get “dire circumstances”. So, yanno, just don’t do that. It’s not like you trigger this problem accidentally; you have to be deliberately trying to undermine the interface by doing something obviously shady; this type doesn’t have `std::shared_ptr`’s converting constructors, so the only way to have two `shared_ptr`s, one a `Base` the other a `Derived` both pointing to the same object, would be explicitly *make* two `shared_ptr`s that way. So just don’t do that.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO But yeah, while I don’t see a reason to be concerned (because the problem won’t happen invisibly; you have to explicitly cause it), it is a bit of a bummer that that won’t work. An even bigger bummer is that you don’t get the power of [aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) (see constructor #8), which is IMO the best feature of `std::shared_ptr`. But to get a smart pointer the same size as a raw pointer, the limitation might be worth it. YMMV. 

Comment: @amon Oh, I certainly believe the costs of the map are high. (And yeah, if concurrency is involved… just forget this design.) If I were trying to design a shared pointer that was only a single pointer in size, I might try doing something *similar* to what you mentioned—the `SharedValue` type. But not *exactly*, because that will bear the cost of a double-indirection on *every* access of the value. I think making copying cheap at the cost of doubling (or much worse, considering cache misses) the cost of access is a poor strategy.

Comment: @amon What I would do is allocate a single chunk of memory that is “`<count><value>`”, and only store the address of the start of the value in the smart pointer. To access the count (which would be an atomic counter, probably `atomic<size_t>`), you’d just have to do some pointer arithmetic… not cheap, but not *that* expensive, and you only pay the cost when copying or destroying. Obviously I’m hand-waving some complexity—you’d need to take alignment into account, for example—but not much.

Comment: @amon The pros: all the same costs of a raw pointer (size and access cost) except when copying/destroying. The cons: no conversions (like derived to base, which `std::shared_ptr` can do), no aliasing, and you can’t take ownership of a pointer—to have the count where it’s supposed to be, the allocation *must* be done by the smart pointer itself. Is this design worth it?  I mean, not to me, because I avoid shared ownership like the plague, and when I *must* use it, the cost of the extra pointer in `std::shared_ptr` doesn’t matter.

Comment: @JDługosz `std::ranges::swap()` has nothing to do with ranges. It just happens to be in that namespace because it was developed along with ranges (and concepts, etc.). It has all the benefits of being a neibloid, which are too many to list here, but for just one: there is no need for the two-step (`using std::swap; swap(...);`), so even if the types change, it will always Just Work™. In C++20 and beyond, it should be the default choice: the question isn’t “why are you using `std::ranges::swap()`?”, it is “why *aren’t* you using it?”.

Comment: @indi (Yes, we're more or less describing the same design. But I'm also describing a single level of indirection, and it doesn't really matter if the shared pointer points to the count or the immediately following value. A statically known pointer offset is free on mainstream architectures. Fortunately, managing the allocation is quite easy and types with exotic alignment requirements are rare.)

Comment: I casting any pointer to std::uintptr_t might be an UB due to different alignment. That may not matter that much if you make the conversion only one-way, but using `void*` would be certainly cleaner.

Comment: @Frax That is not correct. Converting *any* `T*` to `std::uintptr_t` and back is perfectly well-behaved, and will always return the original pointer. (That is true for *any* integer type that is large enough; `uintptr_t` is guaranteed large enough.) Converting any `T*` to `void*` and back is also fine… *but*… you can’t use `void*` as a map key, because comparing random pointer values is UB. (You *can* use `void*` as a key in a `std::unordered_map`, because `std::hash` supports pointer hashing. Internally it just casts the pointer to an integer; both libstdc++ and libc++ use `std::size_t`.)

Comment: The important point in the size analysis is not just total size, but the size of the working set that has to stay hot in cache when code runs that derefs `shared_ptr` members of some other objects.  So keeping `shared_ptr` itself small is very good, especially for arrays, or as part of small objects where pointers are a significant part of it. But the size cost is probably *shifted* from the shared_ptr to the std::(unordered_)map metadata. If your use pattern involves incrementing the ref count, then you're hitting the `std::unordered_map`, too, as well as the control block.

Comment: Anyway, your early paragraphs about how `shared_ptr` is smaller than `std::shared_ptr` phrases things as if `std::map` had no overhead, above the ref counts stored in it.  unordered_map is almost certainly much better for this use-case, especially with huge numbers of shared_ptr objects (hash table vs. RB tree), but you only mention that once at the end, not next to the paragraph where you mention walking a tree being slow for every ownership change.

Comment: If objects are accessed together, they might have been alloced together and might have similar addresses, nearby in a RB tree for good branch prediction and cache locality of their lookups, which you might not have with a hash table?  Still worth mentioning the hash table alternative sooner.

Comment: @indi Oh, I see. Thank you for the detailed explanation, you were absolutely right.

Answer (score 8):

It will leak memory. Aside from not having move constructor or assignment, a big problem is that the assignment operator does not decrease the count for the assigned to object ("`this`", the value on the left of the equals sign). The result is that the memory allocated when `sp5` is constructed is not freed when it is replaced using `sp5 = sp4;`.

One way to check for proper cleanup is to have a check on program exit (after all `shared_ptr` objects should have been destroyed) that `countMap` is empty.

Calling your class `shared_ptr`, while legal, can lead to confusion and possible conflicts if `std::shared_ptr` is used elsewhere in the code. Calling it something else (`my_shared_ptr`, `shared_pointer`, etc.) would avoid that possible confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your review and spotting that memory leak!

Answer (score 6):

#### Design

Your design pays all the costs `std::shared_ptr` does and then some, but drops many of the capabilities.

1. The smart-pointer itself is not smaller (assuming `int` is at least as big as a pointer, or the latter has alignment equal to size).
2. Create and destroy enough of your smart pointers, and your id overflows. Hilarity ensues.
3. The bookkeeping is likely not smaller (a map-node per unique id, 2 * pointer + 2 * number + whatever). `std::shared_ptr` has pointer to functions + managed pointer + 2 * number + stored deallocator (likely optimized out).
4. Independent smart-pointers to the same type aren't independent, as they share the bookkeeping data (map and next id). Thus copying, creating and destroying smart-pointers leads to data races.
5. Creating, copying, or destroying a smart-pointer has to do at least one expensive map-lookup. A big map is a major problem. Not so with `std::shared_ptr`.
6. You cannot point to a sub-object, as doing so looses the association with the right bookkeeping data, and knowledge how to delete the object.
7. You cannot accept a custom deleter. Where to store it?

The first two points can be fixed and the fourth mitigated by mapping directly from payload-pointer to owner-count, but that makes the last two much harder to tackle. Nor does it do anything for three and five. Best redesign properly.

#### Implementation

1. You unconditionally create a managed object in the default ctor. Seems your design must be used with `std::optional` to represent null pointers too.
2. Your copy-ctor and copy-assignment don't accept by constant reference. That is a pointless limitation, as they don't and shouldn't modify the argument.
3. Copy-assignment fails to free the targets resources. Take care to accept self-assignment when fixing that.
4. You have some spurious spaces at the beginning of some of the following lines. Also a spurious doubled space. Consider engaging some auto-formatter.

   ```
   template<typename  dataType>
    int shared_ptr<dataType>::id = 1;
    template<typename  dataType>
    std::map<int,int> shared_ptr<dataType>::countMap;
   ```

#### Testprogram

1. Indentation in `main()` is lacking.
2. `return 0;` is implicit in `main()`.